# How to separate four users in the firebase in android?

Tags: java, android

In my application, I have four users--they have same user login and separate registration. If a doctor log in he will go to the the company activity. How will I make sure that the email is a patient or an doctor or company or pharmacy?

[That image shows my firebase structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBQ8P.png)

Here is my code I try:

```
if (user != null) {
        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("").child(user.getUid()).child("type");
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                if ("doctor".equals(value)) {

                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, doctor_profile.class));
                    finish();
                } else if ("patient".equals(value)) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, PatientActivity.class));
                    finish();
                } else if ("pharmacy".equals(value)) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, PharmacyActivity.class));
                    finish();
                } else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, CompanyActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

So starting from your implementation, you need to check each child that represents a user type to find the id of your user and start the correct `Activity`. There are many ways to solve your problem.

A simple way would be to define a `Map<String, Class>` in which each key is the name of your user type on Firebase (`"Company"`, `"Doctors"`...) and each value associated is the `Class` object of the related `Activity` that you want to start. An example of adding a key-value to this map would be: `mMap.put("Company", CompanyActivity.class);`.

Then you can add a `ValueEventListener()` for each user type and use the map to avoid repeating code:

```
if (user != null) {
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); // find the right path in which your user types live
    for (Map.Entry<String, Class> entry : mMap) {
        ref.child(entry.getKey()).child(user.getUid())
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) { // if value isn't null, then user is of this type and it's possible to start the correct activity
                        Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, entry.getValue());
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled (DatabaseError databaseError){

                }
        });
    }
}
```

This implementation keeps the single login.
If the user has signed in at least one time, you could think about storing its type in the preferences and then check directly the right child in RealTime Database (this is possible only if he doesn't have to log in again, in which case, obviously, you don't know which e-mail the user is going to use).